# Calculating and storing totals in separate JPA Entity in Spring

Tags: java, database, spring, hibernate, jpa

I'm new to Spring, JPA and creating web applications in general and I'm after confusing myself with what is probably a simple problem. I'm trying to create a system which tracks attendance in a venue. I achieve this by implementing computer vision algorithms on a raspberry pi, linked to a camera module. When a person/people enter the building, they are recognised by the Pi, so the timestamp and the number of people who have just entered/left is fired to the server. Here are the fields involved in the Timestamp entity.

```
@Entity
public class Timestamp {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
  private Integer id;

  private DateTime timestamp;

  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "venue_id")
  private Venue venue;

  public Timestamp() {}

  public Timestamp(DateTime timestamp) {
    this.timestamp = timestamp;
  }

  private Integer peopleIn;

  private Integer peopleOut;
```

All good so far. I want to graph information using the highcharts library, exactly like in this example http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/line-time-series/ : 
On the x-axis I will have a date, and on the y-axis I will have the total number of people who walked in the door on that particular day. This is where my problem lies. In order to get the total number of people for each day I must sum all the peopleIn values together for each particular day, but should the date and the total be stored in a separate JPA entity? it wouldn't make sense to have the totalPeople field in the Timestamp entity as i just want the total for each individual day. TLDR; I have the timestamps and the number of people who entered at that moment, how do i get Spring to automatically calculate and store the total number of people for each day. Thank you!

Comment: Do not alter the model in order to suit your logic layer requirements. If a timestamp involves an specific moment with an amount of people entering and others leaving, the entity should reflect exactly that. Then, for calculating the amounts per day, write an SQL query or just load all the timestamps related to one concrete day and calculate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your model is fine, don't hesitate to add the total people entered in each timestamp.
To get the maximum people that entered in a day, formulate your sql, to get the max people that entered between the first and the last timestamp of the same day, sample filter expression is for April 26 2016,

timestamp >= 2016-04-26 00:00:00
and timestamp < 2016-04-27 00:00:00

or any way to that effect. This just gives you the idea on how to logically retrieve your desiref result.